# Error building maven pom - de jetwick snacktory repo unable to read

Tags: java, maven

I am getting an error while building a project using maven.

```
Reason: Error getting POM for 'de.jetwick:snacktory' from the repository: Unable to read local copy of metadata: Cannot read metadata from '/home/user/.m2/repository/de/jetwick/snacktory/1.2-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata-karussell_snapshots.xml': expected = after attribute name (position: TEXT seen ...meta name="selected-link" value="repo_source" data-pjax-transient>... @32:72) 
  de.jetwick:snacktory:pom:1.2-SNAPSHOT
```

This is the error I am getting in IntelliJ IDE log

```
[WARNING] The metadata /home/user/.m2/repository/de/jetwick/snacktory/1.2-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata-karussell_snapshots.xml is invalid: expected = after attribute name (position: TEXT seen ...meta name="selected-link" value="repo_source" data-pjax-transient>... @32:72)
```

This is my pom

```
<repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>karussell_snapshots</id>
            <url>https://github.com/karussell/mvnrepo/tree/master/snapshots/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>snacktory_snapshots</id>
            <url>https://github.com/karussell/mvnrepo/tree/master/snapshots/de/jetwick/snacktory/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>cloudera</id>
            <url>https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
```

This is the dependency part of the pom

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>de.jetwick</groupId>
            <artifactId>snacktory</artifactId>
            <version>1.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the issue solved by changing the version of snacktory to 1.3

```
<version>1.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
```